# Вопрос по laravel route group

Tags: php, laravel

запутался с роутами и namespace. Есть рабочий вариант когда в файле web.php прописать вот так Route::get('/posts', 'App\Http\Controllers\MyPostController@index')->name('post.index');

А когда пытаюсь сделать однофункциональные контроллеры, создаю отдельную папку App\Http\Controllers\Post

Версия Laravel 10 что надо поправить чтобы все заработало)??

[image: Не набочий вариант]

Comment: 1. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 2. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Post'], function (){
        Route::get('/posts', 'IndexController')->name('post.index');
        Route::get('/posts/create','CreateController')->name('post.create');
        Route::get('/posts/{post}','ShowController')->name('post.show');
        Route::post('/posts/create','StoreController')->name('post.store');
        Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit','EditController')->name('post.edit');
        Route::patch('/posts/{post}','UpdateController')->name('post.update');
        Route::delete('/posts/{post`введите сюда код`}','DestroyController')->name('post.delete');
    });
```

Рабочий вариант если вдруг кому понадобится

Answer (score 1):

Нужен сделать так

```
Route::get('/posts',[IndexController::class,'posts']);
```

Comment: Этот способ помог, но надо прописать use  App\Http\Controllers\Post\IndexController;  А можно как-то черех namespace сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\Http\Controllers\{
    IndexController,
    CreateController,
    ShowController,
    StoreController,
    EditController,
    UpdateController,
    DestroyController
};

Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts', 'as' => 'post.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [IndexController::class, 'posts'])->name('index');
    Route::get('/create',[CreateController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
    Route::get('/{post}',[ShowController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
    Route::post('/create',[StoreController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::get('/{post}/edit',[EditController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');
    Route::patch('/{post}',[UpdateController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
    Route::delete('/{post`введите сюда код`}',[DestroyController::class, 'delete'])->name('delete');
});
```

тогда у каждого контроллера должна быть функция с тематическим название (show, edit ...etc)